# Django-Execute function after Celery job completion

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery

I am using **Celery** with **Fabric**. My celery task is copying a file to my local machine Like this:

```
@app.task
def copytolocal():
 get('/home/remote/file.txt','/home/local/') # Copying to local dir
```

When in the view I try to open and read the file I  get an `IOError` because task is not completed yet

```
taskfile.app.send_task('taskfile.copytolocal',[]) # Sending task to queue
open('/home/local/file.txt') #IOError because task isnt completed yet
```

If I use something like `asyncresult.ready()` then it is returning `False` at the execution momement.
Is there any way to implement something like a callback or else and how to do it.

Comment: well it's not clear what you want to do - what should happen in the view if the file is not ready? do you want to make the client wait? or do you want to display a message to the user saying that the file is not ready yet? Personally I'd suggest using a bit of AJAX magic to display a placeholder on the page until the file is ready and then loading an update.

Comment: its typically Get a file(from remote server) -> read the file -> write the content to db. My problem is I want to ensure file read code should get executed after the completion of celery job. Anyway AJAX would be appropriate Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to do

```
while not asyncresult.ready():
    time.sleep(1)

# Now the file is downloaded
```

And if you want it a bit nicer you can use [callbacks](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/tasksets.html#callbacks) where the `link` is a task that is to be performed when the regular task is done.

```
download_file.apply_async(path, link=write_to_db.subtask(path))
```

Comment: perfect exactly I was looking for